# First time using CozyRoc SFTP/SSH components

Tags: ssis

I have to send a file to another site via SFTP.  I've been given a HTTPS URL with an ID/PW. When I access the URL in my browser I see a login page.

When attempting to use the URL/ID/PW with CozyRoc I can't get it to work.  Should this work?  Or do I need to ask the admin for that site for another method since this needs to be automated?

Comment: When I try to setup the connection in CozyRoc, I'm not able to get a response when I test the connection as SSH.  When I tried it as FTP/S connection, I just got AUTH SSL not supported by server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are being given an HTTPS URL then you are not using SFTP, you are using a file upload web app.  You need to ask the admin for that site if they support SFTP and ask for an FTP protocol address to connect to using sftp.  To test that it would work with the CozyRoc component you can use any desktop FTP program that supports SFTP.  If you can connect with one of those (not the browser) then CozyRoc will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, that was my suspicion but since I'm not well versed in file transfer technologies I didn't want to go back to them if there was something I should have inferred from the information they gave me.